# Angular 2 dealing with multiple failed requests requiring an auth token refresh

Tags: authentication, angular, angular2-observables

I am making an Angular 2 frontend for an API that uses access tokens. I am trying to use observables and ngrx/store with this.

Logging in and out works fine and as intended. I have also written some code for when requests fail due the token expiring. This code works okay ordinarily but I run into trouble when I have multiple requests in a short span of time. This happens, for example, when I refresh the page and the app tries to fill two or three stores required across the app.

---

My auth service has functions like these:

```
refreshLogin(): Observable<any> {
    const username = this.currentUser();
    let query = new URLSearchParams();
    query.set('refresh_token', this.refreshToken());
    query.set('grant_type', 'refresh_token');
    return this.getToken(username, query.toString());
}

private getToken(username: string, body: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = Config.AUTH_TOKEN_PATH;
    return this.http.post(url, body)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .do(
            (data) => {
                const token = {
                    username: username,
                    accessToken: data.access_token,
                    refreshToken: data.refresh_token,
                    tokenType: data.token_type,
                    expiresIn: data.expires_in
                };
                this.store.dispatch(AuthActions.loginSuccess(token));
            },
            error => {
                const description = error.json().error_description;
                this.store.dispatch(AuthActions.loginError(description));
                console.error(error);
            }
        )
    ;
}
```

My REST function has a function like this:

```
get(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url, new RequestOptions({ headers: this.authHeader() }))
        .catch(err => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                return this.auth.refreshLogin()
                    .switchMap(() => this.http.get(url, new RequestOptions({ headers: this.authHeader() })))
                    .catch(err2 => err2);
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }                
        })
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    ;
}
```

I don't feel that the functions `currentUser()`, `refreshToken()`, and `authHeader()` are required to understand my question.

---

If I have one failed request and the error is a 401, my app calls `refreshLogin()`, gets a new access token and stores it, and the original request is tried again with the new access token.

If I have more that one failed request, and they are happening effectively at the same time, I run into issues. For example, say I have two GET requests. They both return 401 errors. They both fire off the `refreshLogin()` function. One `refreshLogin()` succeeds and stores a new access token; the other fails because the token being used to refresh is no longer valid. This stream of functions now fails, causing my app to stall.

One solution would be to stack my GET requests in series, but that doesn't seem like it should have to be the case.

I feel like there should be a solution where, on a failed GET (or other) request, the app triggers a call for the access token to be refreshed. The auth service would throttle these requests so there can only be one every couple of seconds or something. It fulfils this request, and the new access token is returned to all the requests to try again.

Do you think this is a sensible approach or am I just trying to patch up an approach that was badly thought out to start with? How would you recommend making these parts interact?

Comment: Hey Man, did you get to solve this problem? If yes how did you solved it, Im encountering the same problem as yours. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @SydneyLoteria. I did fix my problem thanks. It turned out I had the right idea but just didn't know enough about rxjs to make it work. I used `.throttleTime(3000)` to stop more than one refresh request in a three second period. However, I should probably add that I used @ngrx/effects too. So it's actually another observable that gets throttled ... and that observable then calls the `refreshToken` function. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: that throttleTime is new to me :). So you mean I will add the .throttleTime(3000) on the  refreshToken service that will cause to stop all active refreshToken if they are called more than once?

Comment: if its okay with if you can give some example to me. Kinda confused on that throttleTime on how I will used it to my refresh_token service. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've added an answer with my implementation. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, I created a new @ngrx/store action for refreshing my token and consume it using @ngrx/effects. I understand that not everyone will want to use effects but I find it to be very useful it a number of scenarios, not just this one.

So my REST get function now looks like this:

```
get(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url, new RequestOptions({ headers: this.authHeader() }))
        .catch(err => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                this.store.dispatch({type: 'REFRESH TOKEN'});
            }
            return Observable.of(err);
        })
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    ;
}
```

This action is picked up by my effects module ...

```
@Effect() refreshToken$ = this.actions$
    .ofType('REFRESH TOKEN')
    .throttleTime(3000)
    .switchMap(() => this.authService.refreshLogin())
    .map((response) => {
        // Store token
    })
```

Meanwhile, the function/action/whatever that receives the response from the REST get request can determine whether the request was successful or whether it failed because of failed authentication. If it was the latter, it can fire off the request another time (after waiting for the renewed token); otherwise, it can deal with another type of failure in a different way.

Comment: Thanks Man for the samples. Will try this out. For the mean time will learn rxjs and observables it looks like not that simple at first glance :D

Comment: It has taken me a good while to get used to rxjs and reactive programming. But it soon becomes second nature. This intro can help: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

Comment: This works well when you have only one tab, but what if there are two tabs opened, and both tab need to refresh the token at the same time? Both tabs gets a new access token, but only one of them would actually work, the other tab no longer being able to make API requests? That's the problem I'm having :(

Comment: Hit that problem. Still not 100% on the best approach. I'm currently using localStorage and a websockets to manage the token. Update to token comes through ws and is stored. That way, if both tabs save it, the same token is saved. Also, both tabs have access to the same token. Added bonus: if you log out of one tab, you're logged out of the other.